# How to use if else statements in select form?

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

In my registration page, I'm gonna use two drop-down select that one of them should be hidden if its Negative and if its positive new drop-down will open to choose ...

> **In mysql table I've table as diabetes name with enom**
>
> **enum('negative', 'insulin', 'drug', 'ndm', 'mody', '')**

Here's my code:

```html
<div><label for="diabetes">Diabetes:</label>
<select id="diabetes" name="diabetes">
<option value="negative">Negative</option>
<option value="">Positive</option>
</select>
</div>



<div><label for="diabetestype">Diabetes Type:</label>
<select id="diabetestype" name="diabetestype">
<option value="insulin">Insulin</option>
<option value="drug">Drug</option>
<option value="ndm">NDM</option>
<option value="mody">MODY</option>
</select>
</div>
```

For example:  If **Diabetes** is **negative**  value is negative as default then **Diabetes Type** is **hidden**

and

If **Diabetes**  is **positive** then **Diabetes type** will be appeared to choose items.

those values like insulin, drug, mdm, mody should be inserted into this:

**value="positive"**

How can I make it through java script?

I can't add class or div or span. Is it possible just through JavaScript using ??

Thank you so much

Comment: so if value is positive you can choose from the list right ?

Comment: so if Diabetes is positive should be second drop-down will be appeared to choose those values. like insulin, mody and ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery, it is comparatively easier.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#diabetestype").hide();
 $("#diabetes").on("change", function(){
   var v = $(this).val();
   if(v=="positive"){
      $("#diabetestype").show();
   }else{
     $("#diabetestype").hide();
   } 
 });
});
```

To make this code workable, you need to add value of `Positive` option also. So instead `value=""` change it to `value="positive"`.

You can even hide the label also:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#diabetestype").closest("div").hide();
 $("#diabetes").on("change", function(){
   var v = $(this).val();
   if(v=="positive"){
      $("#diabetestype").closest("div").show();
   }else{
     $("#diabetestype").closest("div").hide();
   } 
 });
});
```

Comment: wonderful, amazing. thank you so much. you really helped me and saved me. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
<div><label for="diabetes">Diabetes:</label>
  <select id="diabet" name="diabet" onchange="checkDiabet();">
    <option value="negative">Negative</option>
    <option value="positive" id="isDiabet">Positive</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="type" style="display: hidden;">
  <label for="diabetestype">Diabetes Type:</label>
  <select id="diabetestype" name="diabetestype">
    <option value="insulin">Insulin</option>
    <option value="drug">Drug</option>
    <option value="ndm">NDM</option>
    <option value="mody">MODY</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
function checkDiabet() {
  var isDiabet = document.getElementById("isDiabet").selected;
  if (isDiabet == true) { document.getElementById("type").removeAttribute("style"); }
  else { document.getElementById("type").style.display = "none"; }
}
</script>
```

First, set the first select to fire the function checkDiabet() by the attribute onchange. Then give the option an id, which needs to be checked, so you can access it easily.

Then, set the second select to display: none This could be done in a CSS header or file, or like in this case inline. (div style=""), also add an id to access it easily. (div id="type")

Now comes the function checkDiabete(). It checks if the select is selected (can be true or false (bool)). Is selected => show (div id="type"), if not, hide this div (and all of it's contents)
(if is already hidden, it then overwrites the (style="display: none;") with (style="display: none;))

That's it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function SelectDiabetes() {
  var d = document.getElementById("diabetes").value;
  var dType = document.getElementById("diabetestypebox");
  if(d == "negative")
    dType.style.display = "none";
  else
    dType.style.display = "block";
}

SelectDiabetes();
```

```html
<div><label for="diabetes">Diabetes:</label>
<select id="diabetes" name="diabetes" onchange="SelectDiabetes(this.value);">
<option value="negative">Negative</option>
<option value="positive">Positive</option>
</select>
</div>



<div id="diabetestypebox"><label for="diabetestype">Diabetes Type:</label>
<select id="diabetestype" name="diabetestype">
<option value="insulin">Insulin</option>
<option value="drug">Drug</option>
<option value="ndm">NDM</option>
<option value="mody">MODY</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I got problem with adding new div   <div id="diabetestypebox">    is it possible to change without adding this div id ???   please don't change it to the code, just use diabetestypebox  in other method. is it possible ?

Comment: I did not add a `<div>`, I just assigned an ID to the `<div>` you already had there.

Comment: Actually cause I'm using php framework I can't add new div, for first one i didnt have problem, cause you used onchange , but this one, you added new div, that I cant add it into my php code

Comment: I did not add a `<div>` to the second one. This is your code `<div><label for="diabetestype">Diabetes Type:</label>` and I just gave an ID to the `<div>` that you have there in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Call a js function onchange of select id diabetes

```html
<div><label for="diabetes">Diabetes:</label>
<select id="diabetes" name="diabetes" onchange="toggleTypes()">
<option value="negative">Negative</option>
<option value="">Positive</option>
</select>
</div>



<div><label for="diabetestype">Diabetes Type:</label>
<select id="diabetestype" style="display:none" name="diabetestype">
<option value="insulin">Insulin</option>
<option value="drug">Drug</option>
<option value="ndm">NDM</option>
<option value="mody">MODY</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Use the following javascript

```
function toggleTypes(){
  var el=document.getElementById('diabetes');
  var medElem=document.getElementById('diabetestype');
  if(el.value=='positive') {
    medElem.style.display='block';
  } else {
    medElem.style.display='none';
  }
}
```